# SharePoint Online Nintex form SPGetCurrentUser()

Tags: sharepoint-online, nintex-workflow

I have migrated one SharePoint list from 2019 to 365. This list has Nintex Form and that Nintex form has few JavaScript files. In SP Online `NWF$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser()` is returning blank. Any idea how to fix it? Please keep in mind that this is for Nintex Forms (Not Nintex Workflow)

Comment: Please provide more information, how did you perform the migration? Which migration tool is used?

Comment: we used ShareGate to migrate. It might not have anything to do with migration. If you create new SP list and new Nintex form for SP-Online. And you have some custom JS associated with that form then you will notice that you cannot not use SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser() in that JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this workaround to solve this issue. I added some controls in the form. Now we have new runtime function called userProfileLookup. I used it to populate those controls (e.g user phone, department etc). I accessed value of those controls in JS.